# Merge columns of multiple data frames overwriting values based on column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following data:

```
x<-data.frame(A=c(1,NA),B=c(NA,NA),C=c(NA,1))
   A  B  C
1  1 NA NA
2  NA NA  1
```

and

```
y<-data.frame(A=c(NA,0),C=c(NA,NA),D=c(NA,0))
   A  C  D
1 NA NA NA
2  0 NA  0
```

and I want to merge them in such a way, that columns of the same name are overwritten giving precedence to non - NA values. In addition, columns that are not common should be added.

Desired result:

```
  A  B  C  D
1 1 NA NA NA
2 0 NA  1  0
```

There are no conflicts between non - NA values in my data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. *giving precedence to non - NA values* what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Sotos I think OP is referring to a situation where NAs are to be replaced by any available non-NA values.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

full_join(x,y) %>%
      inner_join(y) %>%
      coalesce(full_join(x,y) %>%
                 inner_join(x))
```

which gives:

```
  A  B  C  D
1 1 NA NA NA
2 0 NA  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method that should be fairly general.

```
# fill in x NA values with values in y
x[] <- lapply(names(x), function(i) ifelse(is.na(x[,i]) & i %in% names(y), y[,i], x[,i]))

# add variables in y that are not in x and provide names to the variables
setNames(cbind(x, y[, !(names(y) %in% names(x))]), union(names(x), names(y)))
  A  B  C  D
1 1 NA NA NA
2 0 NA  1  0
```